# How to add value to an array of objects in react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I want to change value of index 0 object 'sm:true' and on second check create a new object and change value of 'xl:true' of index 1

```
const [size, setSizes] = useState([{sm:false, md:false, lg:false, xl:false,}])

const sizeHandler=(index, value)=>
{
  on first check index is 0 & value = sm:true
  on secondcheck index is 1 & value = xl:true
   if(index===0
    size.map(()=>{
      setSize()
    })
}
```

```
 <FormGroup>
     <FormControlLabel control={<Checkbox />} label="SM"   onChange={()=>sizeHandler(0,{sm:true})} />
   
</FormGroup>

 <FormGroup>     
     <FormControlLabel control={<Checkbox />} label="XL" onChange={()=>sizeHandler(1,{xl:true})} />
</FormGroup>
```

result should be like this:
[{sm:true, md:false, lg:false, xl:false}, {sm:false, md:false, lg:false, xl:true}]

Answer (score 0):

I'm relatively new to js - so hopefully, someone wiser will update/correct this attempted-answer below.

Without going into the UI (FormGroup, FormControlLabel), will try to focus on the actual task/requirement at hand.

Given:

1. An array, initially of size 1, with one object that has 4 specific properties.
2. Array size may increase (not sure if it will decrease as well) and if invoked with index '1' (even though array-size is 1), there must not be any error

Requirement:
Based on the 'index', create additional array-element/s and update the corresponding element (for example if 'index' is 1, then update the 2nd element) with the value being sent used to replace only a part of the object identified at 'index' position.

**Snippet** for quick-checking:

```js
const fixedObj = {
  sm: false,
  md: false,
  lg: false,
  xl: false
};
const dynamicArray = [fixedObj];

/* const [size, setSizes] = useState([{sm:false, md:false, lg:false, xl:false,}]) */


const sizeHandler = (index, value) => {
  // First capture the current array-length
  const currArrLen = dynamicArray.length;
  if (!(index < currArrLen)) { // if 'index' is NOT within the array-length
    for (let i = currArrLen; i < index; i++) { // increase the array-size to match index
      dynamicArray.push(fixedObj); // initialize each new array-element using the fixedObj tempate
    };
  };
  // Now, target the specific array-element, use spread operator to use template, followed by 'value'
  // and update the specific array-element.
  dynamicArray[index] = {
    ...fixedObj,
    ...value
  };
};

sizeHandler(0, {
  sm: true
});
console.log('on first check, update sm to true at index 0, array: ', dynamicArray, '\n\n\n');
sizeHandler(1, {
  xl: true
});
console.log('on second check update xl to true at index 1, array: ', dynamicArray, '\n\n\n');
```